# CSS isn't applied to the HTML in a React app

Tags: html, css, reactjs, load, spinner

On a React app, I have a `Spinner.js` file that `import`s a `Spinner.css` file.

`Spinner.js` code:

```
import React from 'react';

import classes from './Spinner.css';

const spinner = () => (
    <div className={classes.Loader}>Loading...</div>
);

export default spinner;
```

`Spinner.css` code:

```
.Loader,
.Loader::before,
.Loader::after {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.Loader {
  color: #521751;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-indent: -99999em;
  margin: 55px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1em;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.Loader::before,
.Loader::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
.Loader::before {
  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.2em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10.2em 0 0 10.2em;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: -0.1em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 5.2em 5.1em;
  transform-origin: 5.2em 5.1em;
  -webkit-animation: load2 2s infinite ease 1.5s;
  animation: load2 2s infinite ease 1.5s;
}
.Loader::after {
  width: 5.2em;
  height: 10.2em;
  background: rgb(184, 10, 10);
  border-radius: 0 10.2em 10.2em 0;
  top: -0.1em;
  left: 5.1em;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0px 5.1em;
  transform-origin: 0px 5.1em;
  -webkit-animation: load2 2s infinite ease;
  animation: load2 2s infinite ease;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes load2 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

When the page loads, what I get is:

```
<div>Loading...</div>
```

which means that the fallback has been executed and that the CSS code hasn't been applied to the HTML for ***some reason***. How do I figure out that ***reason***?

**EDIT:** Both `Spinner.js` and `Spinner.css` are in the same folder.

Comment: The syntax you provided assumes you are using something like CSS modules or CSS Blocks. Is that the case? Can you provide your webpack file?

Comment: In either case you might want to try making sure your CSS can be compiled the normal way with `import ./Spinner.css` and in your jsx `className="Loader"`

Comment: @MichaelSorensen: I'm not using `Webpack`

Comment: Are you using a webpack alternative? Or is it possible that you developed this application using Create React App?

Comment: @MichaelSorensen: yes, I have actually created it using `Create React App`

Comment: Okay then yeah you will want to follow @kiarashws' answer. Fun fact, Create React App does use webpack but they hide it from the user. They use style loader (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) to compile their CSS. Unfortunately, they have not added the support for CSS modules with their current build. If you feel confident you can try adding it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `import './Spinner.css'`

And in your component use `<div className="Loader">... </div>`

Answer (score 0):

import your css like this-

```
import './Spinner.css';
```

add class to your div like this-

```
<div className="Loader">... </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As a React beginner ill take at shot at this, if im wrong ill learn as well. since you are importing classes already try changing {classes.loader} to {loader} only, lets see if that works out?

heres a link on four ways to link external style sheets to components
[Linking react components to css](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822)

Comment: I'm going to upvote this mostly because I don't want you to lose points on SO so you can still contribute (sue me)

But, just so you know, `{classes.Loader}` is the correct way to import styles when you are using CSS modules. Whether or not he actually is, is another question...

Comment: i appreciate that! and css modules it is indeed. I also notice there is no render() function not sure if that can be an issue. thanks again

Comment: This is just fancy ES6 JSX syntax. If your component is 'stateless' you can render components this way if you so choose.